# How to prevent macroexpand-all to skip first form in list?

Tags: emacs, elisp-macro

I am trying to expand **all macros inside a nested list structure**.
macroexpand-all almost works, but **skips (does not expand) the first form in every nested list**.

I am using this as a template-mechanism for org-agenda-custom-commands. I can generate agenda-blocks for multiple agenda-commands via macros. This is in init.el (emacs26.2). 
macroexp-all-forms is able to not skip the first form, but calls macroexpand-all for nested forms.

Here a minimal example from the emacs doc:

```
(defmacro inc (var)
              (list 'setq var (list '1+ var)))
```

This works as expected (one macro-call):

```
ELISP> (macroexpand-all '(inc r))
(setq r
      (1+ r))
```

This works too (nested, but first form is not a macro-call):

```
ELISP> (macroexpand-all '(('foo)(inc r)))
(('foo)
 (setq r
       (1+ r)))
```

This does **NOT** work (nested and first form is a macro-call):

```
ELISP> (macroexpand-all '((inc r)(inc r)))
((inc r)
 (setq r
       (1+ r)))
```

This also does **not** work:

```
ELISP> (macroexpand-all '((inc r)))
((inc r))
```

In the last two examples, the **first call to inc is not expanded**. What am I missing here?
How can i really expand all macros in this situation?

Answer (score 3):

`macroexpand-all` expects a [form](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Forms.html) as the argument, but `((inc r) (inc r))` is not a form. A form should be something that can be evaluated. In the case of a list, that means the first element must be a name of a function, macro or a special operator, or a lambda expression.

The special operator `progn` can be used for a list of forms to be evaluated sequentially. For example:

```
(macroexpand-all '(progn (inc r) (inc r)))
;=> (progn
;     (setq r
;           (1+ r))
;     (setq r
;           (1+ r)))
```

Alternatively, if the list is not meant to be a form, you can use `mapcar` to apply `macroexpand-all` to each member of the list. For example:

```
(mapcar #'macroexpand-all '((inc r) (inc r)))
;=> ((setq r
;          (1+ r))
;    (setq r
;          (1+ r)))
```

Keep in mind that the result here is a list of forms, but not a form itself; it cannot be evaluated as is, but the individual elements can be.

Answer (score 1):

The form you want to expand should make sense as a form for evaluation.  `((inc r))` does not: it can't be legal elisp.

I'm actually fairly surprised that `macroexpand-all` doesn't raise an error in the case you've given it.  If you want it to work you need to fake up something which is potentially legal.  For instance

```
ELISP> (macroexpand-all '(grut (inc r) (inc r)))
(grut
 (setq r
       (1+ r))
 (setq r
       (1+ r)))

ELISP> (cdr (macroexpand-all '(grut (inc r) (inc r))))
((setq r
       (1+ r))
 (setq r
       (1+ r)))
```

`grut` does not need to be defined: it only needs not to be a macro so `macroexpand-all` just ignores it.  (In fact, using `progn` as [jkiiski suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57820051/5920214) is a better answer).

As an aside, it sounds like you are using macroexpansion to do something other than expand Lisp code: that's almost always a bad idea.  It's much better to write your own expander which understands the rules of the language you are implementing in Lisp.